# BIG Resource eater

Tags: php, jquery

This script is eating up a lot of resource on my members computers. I have other interval scripts that don't eat up any resource. I've tried extending the time but that slows down the refresh. Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
  updatestatus();
  scrollalert();
});
function updatestatus(){
  //Show number of loaded items
  var totalItems=$('#scontent p').length;
  $('#status').text('Done');
}
function scrollalert(){
  var scrolltop=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollTop');
  var scrollheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollHeight');
  var windowheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('clientHeight');
  var scrolloffset=10;
  if(scrolltop>=(scrollheight-(windowheight+scrolloffset)))
  {
    //fetch new items
    $('#status').text('Loading more members...');
    $.get('allonline.php', '', function(newitems){
      $('#scontent').load('allonline.php');
      updatestatus(); 
    });
  }
  setTimeout('scrollalert();', 60000); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing what's being brought back from 'allonline.php', I'm just guessing.  But the one area that stands out is the fact that you have a `$.get()` function that requests 'allonline.php' and in it's callback you `load()` 'allonline.php' again.  Seems like you're requesting the same chunk of data twice, but only using it once.

Can you replace

```
$.get('allonline.php', '', function(newitems){
    $('#scontent').load('allonline.php');
    updatestatus(); 
});
```

...with:

```
$('#scontent').load('allonline.php', function() { updatestatus(); });
```

You're not using `newitems` in your `$.get()` callback, so I think this should work.

Other things to check:

1. size of response from allonline.php -- if it's large, and you're requesting it twice, it could take a browser some time to re-render the DOM;
2. browser your clients are using...IE7 is SLOW, IE6 is SLOOOOWWWWWER;
3. class of machine clients are using

Again, without knowing what's being returned, I'm speculating.  But the double request to allonline.php seems to be a culprit.

I hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: That's probably the main problem. Other things: instead of calling '$(#foo') over and over again for the same element, cache that somewhere. Also, the `setTimeout` call should just be `setTimeout(scrollAlert, 6000);`